# How to grep diacritics with pdfgrep

Tags: pdf, grep, special-characters, diacritics

I just install pdfgrep on my win server 2012 using cgywin and it's work fine except for special chars with diacritics, when I type:

```
pdfgrep -i -H -c -r confirme /cygdrive/c/Users/Administrateur/Desktop
```

it's returning the name of each pdf on my Desktop with the numbers of "confirme" appears in but if I type:

```
pdfgrep -i -H -c -r développement /cygdrive/c/Users/Administrateur/Desktop
```

all I get is: 'pdfgrep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced'

Anybody knows how can I grep those charactere ?

Comment: Try with `"développement"` -- quoted. (For this to work, the Unbalanced Brackets error would have to be unrelated. But it might be a parsing error in your PDF, related to accented characters.)

Comment: I already try this and it's the same, with simple or doubl quote

Comment: Try with wildcards, then, and see what pdfgrep *thinks* is there. Reading even plain text out of a PDF is Black Art; characters out of the regular ASCII range even more so.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean (i'm from france and not really confortable with English) so I try to insert wildcards like that: "*veloppement", "%veloppement" with the * there is an error because it's made for repetition expretion ingrep expretion and with the % in doesn't see him as a wildcards but as a normal char so he found nothing

Comment: I up this post, I hope someone could help me, I don't have any solution right now :(

Comment: There may not be much interest in your post because it is not primarily **programming-related**. Searching the web, I see similar questions for `pdfgrep` are asked on [Super User Stackexchange](http://superuser.com/) instead.